# Is i7-3770k really worth buying than i5-3570k?

Tags: processor

The current price of i7-3770k in my place is (7000PHP) ~ 130USD while i5-3570k is only (3500PHP) ~ 65USD.

Is the extra 4 threads really to pay for a double price? I mean it is not a real core right? They are both quad-core processor but the i7 has 4 more threads than i5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to comparing CPUs in an objective way without having them on hand, the quickest way to estimate how a processor will perform, and therefore, its value you is to look at [benchmarks between the processors](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-vs-Intel-Core-i5-3570K/1317vs1316). Here, we can see the effective speed is pretty negligible, but the average user benchmark for multi core scenarios is markedly faster.

> I mean it is not a real core right?

Well, it depends on what you define as a "real core". Take a look at Intel's article on its [Hyper Threading technology](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hyper-threading/hyper-threading-technology.html) for a sense of the mechanics behind the theoretical cores.

In terms of "is it a real core" in a "does it do anything?" sense, the 4 theoretical cores does make a measurable impact as the i7 has a faster Multi Core Integer and Floating Point calculation speed by about 33% and a bench marked multi core speed of +39%.

> Are the extra 4 threads really worth paying double the price?

The four extra cores on the i7 are "theoretical" or hyper thread cores.

Whether it is worth it, really depends on your user case scenario. Something like video encoding may benefit more from the increased multi-thread speed, while a *badly* written single threaded game might not see as much benefit.

**My guess is if this computer is going to be for general use, you could probably get away with the i5.** Computer enthusiasts making gaming builds typically downgrade to i5 variants of their i7 processor when their budget demands it, as it is usually better to reallocate those resources for a higher end GPU.